# What is the dereference operator telling the compiler to do during multidimensional array references?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I've been playing around with multidimensional arrays and bracket notation, trying my best to come up with a conceptual understanding of the interplay between dereferencing, pointer type, and pointer arithmetic.

For this problem, consider the following arbitrary 3D array reference:

```
    arr[i][j][k]
```

Now, I believe the following conversion is equivalent (I've run a few code examples that I believe confirms the accuracy):

```
    *(*(*(arr+i)+j)+k)
```

The code I ran looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char arr[2][3][4] = { 'a', 'b' ,'c' ,'d' ,'e' ,'f' ,'g' ,'h' ,'i' ,'j' ,'k' ,'l' ,'m' ,'n' ,'o' ,'p' ,'q' ,'r' ,'s' ,'t' ,'u' ,'v' ,'w' ,'x' };

    printf("%c \n", arr[1][1][1]);

    printf("%c \n", *(*(*(arr+1)+1)+1));

    return 0;
}
```

You can change up the values in the `printf` statements (so long as the values for `i`,`j`, and `k` are the same between the two). At any rate, they always agree on what letter is printed out to the command terminal.

The way I acquired this presumed equivalent answer is depicted in the below picture (sorry, I used the math stack exchange writing software as it made everything a little bit easier... if the notation for the pointer arithmetic is a little confusing, I apologize.)

---

[image: Derivation]

---

So my main confusion arises from the dereference operator `*`. Quite frankly, **I don't understand what it is telling the compiler to do**.

For a simple example, let's assume that the character array `arr` starts at a base address of 100.

`arr` is effectively a pointer that points to a 2D matrix of type `char[3][4]`. I believe that means (because a character requires 1 byte) the code `arr + 1` is actually saying `100+12`. Rewriting my equation, I would then have:

`*(*(*(112)+1)+1)`. I am fairly certain that the dereference operator (to the left of `112`) takes left-to-right precedence over the `+` symbol (to the right of `112`).

From my experience with the dereference symbol in 1D cases, this would produce the value stored at the 112 memory cell. **But this just seems wrong in the current situation**. Clearly, I am not understanding how the dereference operation behaves in this context. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers~

Comment: You've misplaced brackets somewhere getting from `*(arr+1)` to `*(112)+1`   . Also replacing arrays by integers is not a valid transformation , since pointer arithmetic is different to integer arithmetic

Comment: @M.M I'm not sure I follow your comment. `(112)` is derived from `(arr+1)` so I don't understand where the bracket would have been misplaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the pointers in C are not integers, they have distinct types, and those used with the array indexing operator or pointer arithmetic must refer to objects of *complete type*, i.e. whose size is *known* where they are used.

The declaration

```
char arr[2][3][4];
```

could be read *`arr[i][j][k]` is of type `char`*.

It also tells that `arr` itself is of type `char[2][3][4]`. Each first-level element, i.e. `arr[i]` is of type `char[3][4]` and each 2nd level element is of type `char[4]`. If you do `sizeof` on these types,

- `sizeof(char)` is 1
- `sizeof(char[4])` is 4
- `sizeof(char[3][4])` is 12
- `sizeof(char[2][3][4])` is 24

Now, in almost *any* context, an expression of array type is said to *decay* to a pointer to the *first* element. That applies to `arr` too. Since the first element of `arr` is `arr[0]`, and from above the type or `arr[0]` is that of `arr[i]` i.e. `char[3][4]`, the resulting type is a *pointer* to a `char[3][4]`; which in C is written as `(char *)[3][4]`.

If you add an integer to that pointer, the resulting pointer will point to the nth (0-based) object of *that* type.

I.e. `arr + 0` would result in a pointer that points to the *first* `char[3][4]` subarray of the array; `arr + 1` to the *second* and so forth. Also, `arr + n` would point at the *memory location* (byte) which is `n * sizeof(char[3][4])` bytes (also `n * sizeof(arr[0])`) from the beginning of `arr`.

Now, if we *dereference* that pointer, e.g. `*(arr + 1)`, the resulting expression will be an *array* of type `char[3][4]`. But that value would immediately decay to a pointer to the first element of that array; the elements of that array are of type `char [4]`, and the pointer type would be `char (*)[4]`.

If we add an integer, as above, we get a pointer to the nth `char[4]` subarray of that array; i.e. with `(*(arr + 1) + 1)`. Now if we dereference that pointer `*(*(arr + 1) + 1)`, we have an expression of type `char[4]`, but it immediately decays to a pointer to the first element. Since the elements of `char[4]` are characters, the type would be plain and simple Garak... err `char *`.

Now if we add an integer to that, we get a pointer to the nth *element* in the `char[4]` array (e.g. `(*(*(arr + 1) + 1) + 1)` , and if we dereference this (`*(*(*(arr + 1) + 1) + 1)`), we get an lvalue of type `char` which designates this certain character within the array.

---

Why is dereferencing operator needed then? Of course to refere to the subobjects.

If you remove the stars, `(((arr + 1) + 1) + 1)` would be actually equal to `arr + 3`, which would be the pointer to `arr[3]`, i.e. the *4th* `char[3][4]` subarray of `arr`. Since `arr` only had *2* such subarrays, not only would it fail to do what you wanted, but that would result in *the dreaded undefined behaviour*.

---

TL;DR:

Given the above definition, `arr + 1`  and `*(arr + 1)`, after decay, will result in pointers pointing to the **same** memory location, but having **distinct types**.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you need to understand:

- Arrays are not pointers, even though they are automatically converted to pointers in most situations.
- Multi-dimensional arrays get zero special treatment compared to one-dimensional arrays. They **are** one-dimensional arrays, where each element is also an array.

---

When you do `*(*(*(arr+1)+1)+1)`, `arr` is automatically converted to the pointer to its first element. This pointer has type `char(*)[3][4]` (pointer to `char[3][4]`). Adding `1` to it increases the value of the pointer by `1*sizeof(char[3][4]) == 12`. You seem to already know this.

Dereferencing the resulting pointer gives you an lvalue of type `char[3][4]`, **which in turn decays** to pointer of type `char(*)[4]` equal to `&arr[1][0]`. Adding `1` to that pointer increments it by `1*sizeof(char[4])`, after that it's equal to `&arr[1][1]`.

Dereferencing the resulting pointer gives you an lvalue of type `char[4]`. It also decays to a pointer of type `char *` equal to `&arr[1][1][0]`. After adding `1` to it, its value increases by `1*sizeof(char)` and becomes equal to `&arr[1][1][1]`. Then the final dereference gives you the value of `arr[1][1][1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Subscripting arrays and pointers has the same meaning: `a[i]` tells the compiler to compute the address of the `i`-th element of the array. This address will be read if you use `a[i]` in an rvalue.

If `a` is a pointer, this computation requires reading the contents of the pointer and adding `i` times the size of the array element to it.

If `a` is an array, this computation just involves adding `i` times the size of the array element to the address of the array.

In both cases, `a[i]` can be rewritten as `*(a+i)` because, if `a` is an array, it automatically decays as a pointer to its first element in the expression `a+i`. This is conceptually equivalent to:

```
    int a[10];
    int i, x;

    x = a[i];

    int *a_ = &a[0];
    x = *(a_ + i);
```

Note that the `*` in `*(a+i)` causes the address computed by `a+i` to be read if the value is used in an rvalue context, such as `x = *(a+i);` or written to if it appears in an lvalue context: `*(a+i) = x;`. The statement `*(a+i);` neither reads nor writes the array element (unless `a` is declared `volatile`).

With your example, `char arr[2][3][4]`, `arr[0][0][0]` has the same address as `arr[0][0]`, `arr[0]` and `arr`, they just have different types.